# Simple ajax-call to get Typepad blog's atom.xml

Tags: ajax, json, typepad

So I have a Typepad blog and want to load some posts in to my own website. I looked at the Typepad API but it seemed overly complex. Typepad also supplies a widget, but that only shows post titles and hrefs and I need the content too.

So here's what I'm doing, I have jQuery included in the page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://notes2self.typepad.com/notes/atom.xml?callback=?',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(feed) {
        console.log(feed);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

It logs "success" but the object logged looks like an XMLHttpRequest response where I want it to simply return the xml contents:

> Object {readyState: 4, status: 200, statusText: "success"}

Also, in Chrome on OSX, the console logs an error on line 1 of atom.xml:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I'm obviously doing some very basic things wrong. Any tips to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here that the return type is invalid. If you go to http://notes2self.typepad.com/notes/atom.xml?callback=? then you'll get the results in XML (check the source).

Your jQuery is expecting a return type of JSON, and thus not able to parse the results. This is shown in the Chrome error message with the unexpected "<" character.

To prove this, try:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://notes2self.typepad.com/notes/atom.xml?callback=?',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(feed) {
        console.log(feed);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

and see if there's any results coming back (feed).

This posts describes how to accomplish XML-based return types for cross-domain requests: http://www.isgoodstuff.com/2012/07/22/cross-domain-xml-using-jquery/